# table can not be created in Postgres using jpa and hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I try to generate tables in PostgreSQL using hibernate and jpa but that does not work, there is no error in the console.

```
spring.datasource.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/pfeDb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=Nstg_Correlation
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

and this is the entity

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Catalogue implements Serializable{

 @Id
  private Long id_catalogue;

  private String nom_catalogue;
  private String description;
  private String sujet_catalogue;
  private boolean nouveau_catalogue;
  private boolean edition_en_cours;
  private String commentaire_catalogue;

  }
```

and this is the main class:

```
package pfe.app.PFE_DelphiToJav;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
@Component
public class PfeDelphiToJavApplicationTests {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PfeDelphiToJavApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

Comment: I see no error. Where is it?

Comment: show your JPA configuration

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda I used spring boot

Comment: try to change dialect to `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda thank you for your help, I did the opposite I generate classes from the dataBase but the mapping is generated with a looot of errors :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@Table` annotation to your entity.

```
@Entity
@Table
@Getter 
@Setter 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Catalogue implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private Long idCatalogue;
    private String nomCatalogue;
    private String description;
    private String sujetCatalogue;
    private boolean nouveauCatalogue;
    private boolean editionEnCours;
    private String commentaireCatalogue;

}
```

Btw use camel case instead of snake case for java fields, variable etc.

Comment: there is no change, I add @table